# ATTrackingManager & UMPConsentInformation both are required for AdMob?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, attrackingmanager

I have a question like for Google AdMob iOS we have to ask for `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` and after that, we have to ask `UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate`

Another question is from `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` if user is not authorised then we can ask for `UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate` because user already permitted to not track.

And last one is we can just ask for `UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate` UMP Consent information only? Because on GoogleAdmob SDK there is no any code for `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization`.

Comment: Yes/No, one of them is for GDPR (more stringent) and the other is for Apple. Two different permissions one has legal implications and the other is to allow you to see the IDFA. If you don’t want to use IDFA don’t ask for it but your income will be less and you’ll get less detail.

Comment: @loremipsum so like if user not allowed for Tracking then also I can show UMP Consent form? Because earlier I added that and apple rejected app with reason like after don't allow tracing you can't Consent.

Comment: That is probably something new from Apple but it makes sense. If the user doesn’t want their IDFA to be used they aren’t going to want all the advertisers getting whatever other info. I’ve published 2 apps with UMP before and just followed the steps online and had no issues but that was a while ago.

Comment: I think we need to show both. ATTrackingManager requirement is imposed by Apple (and EU?) and UMPConsentInformation requirement is imposed by Google (and EU?). I think we need to fulfill both parties, if we want to fully comply in both iOS and Admob platforms. But, it isn't clear which popup we should display first.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

If you use Google UMP SDK you only need to configure `UMPConsentInformation` in your code and then add relevant messages in the AdMob UI - Google will take care of when and if to display that messages (and in which order).

#### Explanation

According to the [Google AdMob website](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy/gdpr#frequently_asked_questions) if you use their UMP SDK you don't need to manually request ATT permission.

> **What is the best practice for showing both the iOS ATT alert and GDPR consent to the same user?**
>
> We recommend showing the GDPR consent message first and the iOS ATT alert second if the user consented to GDPR. This is already handled by the UMP SDK if you configure both messages in the AdMob UI. See [Which message your users will see](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10115027#which_message) for more information.
>
> If you are not showing the ATT alert using the UMP SDK, we recommend you read consent choices once GDPR consent is collected to determine whether to show the iOS ATT alert.

Here are the possible variants:

[image]

You mainly have two options:

- Use Google UMP SDK - then you just need to setup your app to use `UserMessagingPlatform` and configure relevant messages on AdMob UI.
- Use other certified UMP - then Google recommends to display the GDPR consent form first and then basing on the responses determine whether to show the ATT message.

---

#### Guide

Here are the main steps (that I'm currently using in some of my apps):

1. Import `UserMessagingPlatform` - it is contained in GoogleMobileAds:

```
import AppTrackingTransparency
import GoogleMobileAds
import UserMessagingPlatform
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start

2. Link `AppTrackingTransparency` - you won't use it in code but Google UMP will use it to create a popup for you:

Reference: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy/idfa

Also you need to add the below key to the `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you.</string>
```

3. Configure the UMP SDK as explained here:

- [UIKit](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy)
- [SwiftUI](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy/swiftui)

All you need is `UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance` - there's no need to add anything related with `ATTrackingManager`.

Also make sure to follow additional steps like delaying the app measurement: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy/gdpr

4. Configure [AdMob UI](https://apps.admob.com/v2/privacymessaging):

[image]

Here you need to add both:

- a GDPR message
- an IDFA explainer

Once you setup them in the AdMob UI they'll be shown for the apps that are using the Google UMP SDK.

*Note: Just make sure to select the correct app when creating a new message.*

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this solution earlier on various app it's working for me.

`UMPSDK` it's introduce due to privacy purpose in [EU User Consent Policy](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy)

> I have a question like for Google AdMob iOS we have to ask for
> ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization and after that, we have
> to ask UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate

No we don't need to ask `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` now because it's already covered by `UMPSDK` so whenever we implemented `UMPSDK` we need to setup `GDPRMessage` from `ADMob` account.
This message will present while calling it.

```
let parameters = UMPRequestParameters()

//For testing purposes, you can force a UMPDebugGeography of EEA or not EEA.
let debugSettings = UMPDebugSettings()
// debugSettings.geography = UMPDebugGeography.EEA
parameters.debugSettings = debugSettings

// Requesting an update to consent information should be called on every app launch.
UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate(with: parameters) {
  requestConsentError in
  guard requestConsentError == nil else {
    return
  }

  UMPConsentForm.loadAndPresentIfRequired(from:self) { 
    loadAndPresentError in

    // Consent has been gathered.
    // Whenever consent will click ATTrackingManager popup present
  }
}
```

> Another question is from
> ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization if user is not
> authorised then we can ask for
> UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate because
> user already permitted to not track.

For this answer you need visit [User ATTrackingManager Journey](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10115027)

> And last one is we can just ask for
> UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate UMP
> Consent information only? Because on GoogleAdmob SDK there is no any
> code for ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization.

[image]

There are two types of form for two type of different `EEA` & `not EEA` users.
`EEA` user will see GDPR dialogue where `consent` button will visible to form and when user click on it it will present `ATTrackingManager` dialogue.
GDPR Message Form: [image]

`not EEA` user will see IDFA dialogue where `continue` button will visible to form and when user click on it it will present `ATTrackingManager` dialogue.
IDFA Message Form: [image]

**How to setup GDPR & UMP**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwcrESnAYEI&t=2s&ab_channel=GoogleAdMob

**Google ads with UMP demo**

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples